# Why isnt my Google Analytics code tracking data across all domains?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
 _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
 _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']); 
 _gaq.push(['_setLocalRemoteServerMode']);  
 _gaq.push(['_setLocalGifPath', 'http://www.example.com/__utm.gif']); 
 _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]); 
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type ='text/javascript';ga.async = true; 
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl':'http://www')+ '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];   s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

I cannot display the actual websites and content so I changed the websites to random.com and the two websites that are not being tracked to example1 and example2.com Also the main website is example.com

This is a external js file that has GA tracking code. That is in the head tag of example.com It also has the cross tracking section with it. In var domains[ example1.com and example2.com] dont actually get tracked via google analytics.

I do not have access to external js file. So what I am wondering if there is a error in the way it was written.

I believe the problem could be one of  three things or I am completely wrong ;
1.) example1 and example2 are actually within the website so subdomains not different domains.

2.) Or that it is not running through the whole array. Because all domains in var domains have push data into google analytics except example1.com and example2.com.

3.) Or gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true] needs to be gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker',  [here the domains] true]

Edit: Removed irrelevant pieces of code

Comment: Could you trim the virtual pageview code for downloads and external links from your code example ? That does not seem important to the question and makes it a lot harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. So i needed to ignore most of the code.

```
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
 _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
 _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);
 _gaq.push(['_setLocalRemoteServerMode']);  
 _gaq.push(['_setLocalGifPath', 'http://www.example.com/__utm.gif']); 
 _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]); 
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type ='text/javascript';ga.async = true; 
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl':'http://www')+ '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];   s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

This is the only relevant part. I needed to delete

```
_gaq.push(['_setLocalRemoteServerMode']); //Pulls remote GA code for Urchin 
 _gaq.push(['_setLocalGifPath', 'http://www.example.com/__utm.gif']);
```

It seems this is outdated classic GA code after that the websites worked fine.